# Database Schema for Multi-Color Products

Tags: mysql, database, relationship, product

I am designing a database and would like some feedback on what I have so far.

Here are the requirements:
Each product has multiple colors.
Each product must be under a certain category.
Each category may have a subcategory.

**A example relationship would be**

```
Eyes[Cat]
   EyeProduct[Product]
      Color1[color]
      ...
      ColorN[color]

Lips[Cat]
   Lipgloss[Subcat]
      CoolLipgloss[Product]
          Color1[color]
          ...
          ColorN[color]
```

Here is my database design so far:

```
Categories
-id     (pk)
-subcat_id  (fk)
-name
-description
-active     (boolean)

Sub Category
-id         (pk)
-product_id     (fk)
-name
-description


Products
-id     (pk)
-name
-price
-weight
-descritpion
-ingredients
-product_img
-active     (boolean)

SKU
-sku    (pk)
-product_id     (fk)
-name
-image_small
-image_med
-image_Lrg
-active     (boolean)
```

Would it be a good idea to implement a image tables. This table will hold a reference to all images used for each SKU (color) and any extra product images. I think it makes more sense since each sku entry can have more than one picture as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. Just couple notes regarding relationships (fk), I think they should be changed:

```
Categories
-id     (pk)
-name
-description
-active     (boolean)

Sub Category
-id         (pk)
-category_id     (fk)
-name
-description


Products
-id     (pk)
-subcategory_id     (fk)
-name
-price
-weight
-descritpion
-ingredients
-product_img
-active     (boolean)

SKU
-sku    (pk)
-product_id     (fk)
-name
-image_small
-image_med
-image_Lrg
-active     (boolean)
```

BTW. You can use partial path for images, this will save you 2 text fields.
For example you have 3 images for sku 1111:

```
/tmp/image1111small.jpg
/tmp/image1111med.jpg
/tmp/image1111lrg.jpg
```

Actually only "/tmp/image1111" have to be stored, and full path would be restored by adding "small.jpg", "med.jpg" and "lrg.jpg" to the path accordingly.